# Change key in c#

Tags: c#, keyboard, keyboard-shortcuts

I need to change keys in c#.

Example : if press on "a" then "b" pressing.

Something like this:

```
Key.change("a","b"); // a = key , b = value
```

Please note this : key is static and value is dynamic, it's meaning : key = (always) "a" , value = (can be change) "b" || "c" || "d",etc

So if this problem solving with simply way i really glad.

Thanks and sorry for poor english.

Comment: What is `inputbox1` ?

Comment: And what type of application is this?

Comment: Is it for your own personal use or is it for the user?

Comment: Oh thanks for your fast replays,
This is C# , inputbox or button is not important , 
I just want to change keys...
@JonSkeet

Comment: Please note this : 
key is static and value is dynamic,
it's meaning : 
key = (always) "a" , value = (can be change) "b" || "c" || "d",etc

Comment: Yes, it's C#... But Windows Forms? WPF? Web? UWP? Something else?

Comment: @JonSkeet 
i can send my full project to you.

Comment: No, that's not how Stack Overflow works. It's not a consultancy service. The point is to make a repository of useful questions for the future - you sending me the project doesn't help that. What *would* help that is providing a [mcve] in the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On the Form class, add this method & variable :

```
char change = 'b';
private void ChangeKey(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.KeyChar=='a')
    {
            e.KeyChar = change;
    }
}
```

Then either on Load or Form constructor, subscribe to each of input control you have, manually

```
textBox1.KeyPress += ChangeKey;
textBox2.KeyPress += ChangeKey;
```

or all of them

```
 foreach (var item in Controls.OfType<Control>())
 {
    item.KeyPress += ChangeKey;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
private void textBox1_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.KeyChar > (char)001 )
        {
            e.KeyChar++;

        }
    }
```

also works.